# Does development environment on Net Core 6 implies that it reads configurations from appsettings.Development first?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

Good morning guys, just a simple question regarding this little builder snippets in Program.cs.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SteelworksContext>(options =>
{
   if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
   {
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SteelworksDev"));   //from appsettings.Development
   }
   else
   {
       options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Steelworks"));  //from appsettings
   }
});
```

Does that code implies that if condition is true the connection string is read from appsettings.Development or it just reads from appsettings as it normally does?

Comment: FYI: You can test these things.

Comment: How? I don't have access to prod server yet so until I deploy I can't test it

Comment: That's a confusing statement. By default in local dev, the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is set to "Development", which is what causes it to read from asppsettings.Development.json, but you can set it to whatever you like. This will also change the result of `builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()`.

Comment: Honestly, the code above seems redundant anyway: why not set the Steelworks connection string in both `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.json`, and let the environment determine which one is used?

Comment: It is actually set in both, SteelworksDev in appsettings.Dev whereas Steelworks in appsettings, my concern was to make the reading automated, i don't really now if Net Core makes a check on which env is being used when I start the app, so I added that condition

Comment: Change the value of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` between Development, Staging, and Release, and you'll be able to see for yourself.

Comment: Ok I'll try. I think I kind of figured it out thanks to your replies and the guy below

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the config settings have been loaded into the program but that would be a reasonable assumption to make.

You should look at the code that loads the config settings (this might be in a `Startup` class but will depend on your project).

FYI: It looks like the connection string has a different name in the appsettings & appsettings.Development config files. This is unnecessary and somewhat defeats the point of having the two files. Both files should just have the same connection string name e.g. `"Steelworks"` and only one line of code that sets up the `DbContext`:

```
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Steelworks"));
```